# CAKEPHP3 controller avoid action

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I'm new to CakePHP...
Can anyone help me about this:

I have a Controller that I want to maintain in the URL not search an action, i.e: `site.com/controller/SKU01B` not seek for action `SQU01B` but search by product with `SKU`, the same will occur when typed `site.com/product/view/1`.

I think:

```
$routes->connect('/site/SKU*', ['controller' => 'Site', 'action' => 'index']);
```

but it didn't work, nor with `?` instead of `*`.

Can anyone help me how can I do it?

Comment: You may want to read **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#route-elements** and **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#passing-parameters-to-action** (more closely).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use:**

```
Router::connect('/sku/*', array('controller' => 'yourcontroller', 'action' => 'view'),array('pass' => array('id')));
```

**and**

```
function view($id=null){   

         // $id will be sku
         // For example, http://www.example.com/product/12345 here $id is 12345

}
```

Comment: thnx! Was not exactly what I need, I was did something like this and the client refused, but I will use this way.